# C# Array of dictionaries with defined dimensions

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, custom-type

I'm trying to define a custom type for my project. I will try to explain what I'm trying to achieve. I have n*m packets. each packet has a different composition (mass of CO2, H2O, NO, CO , ...). I want to store the composition of all packets in my custom type.
The composition of each packet can be a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, double>
```

as an example :

```
packetComposition["CO2"]  = 2.6;
packetComposition["O2"]  = 1.7;
```

The point is that all these dictionaries should be stored in some sort of n*m array. So I can have composition of all n*m packets in one place.

Obviously this array can't be something like double[,] or int[,] , ... because the content will be a dictionary and not an `int` or `double`.

Any idea how to store all these dictionaries in a custom type of n*m dimension?
Thanks

Comment: List<Dictionary<string, double>>? Can you explain in more detail what you are looking for? How are you planning on using this custom type?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>`. Instead of `string` you could also use an `enum` as key for the outer dictionary to describe the different `CompositionType`

Comment: What's wrong with `Dictionary<string, double>[,]`? Two-dimensional arrays don't have to be built-in value-types.

Comment: Seems like you should create your own class for every composition and store a list opf those instances.

Comment: Can you explain why you used `Dictionary` and how you plan to use your custom type? There are a lot of types out there to deal with things like this. It would really help if you can go a bit further on the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use a `Dictionary<string, double>[,]` to hold your data:

```
var packets = new Dictionary<string, double>[2, 3]
{
    { new Dictionary<string, double>(), new Dictionary<string, double>(), new Dictionary<string, double>(), },
    { new Dictionary<string, double>(), new Dictionary<string, double>(), new Dictionary<string, double>(), },
};

packets[1, 0]["CO2"] = 2.6;
packets[1, 1]["CO2"] = 2.4;
packets[1, 2]["CO2"] = 2.9;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own packet type which will contain all the compounds, for example

```
 public class Packet
 {
      public Dictionary<string, decimal> Compounds { get; }

      public Packet()
      {
           Compounds = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
      }
 }
```

And you can use it like this

```
List<Packet> packets = new List<Packet>();

Packet packet = new Packet();
packet.Compounds.Add("CO2", 2.6);
packet.Compounds.Add("O2", 1.7);

packets.Add(packet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own class for this. Then you can easily create instances and put them into a list:

```
class Composition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now put them into a multidemensional array:

```
Composition[,] myInstances = new Composition[n,m];
myInstanes[0,0] = new Composition { Name = "CO2", Value = 2.6 };
myInstanes[0,1] = new Composition { Name = "O2", Value = 1.7 };
```